# Deprecated getPlayer() from Server

Tags: java, eclipse, bukkit

The following piece of code gives an error saying it's deprecated.

```
Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
```

Here's my plugin:

```
package me.herobrine112211.ulticmdpack;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class System extends JavaPlugin {

    public void onEnable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Ultimate Command Pack Plugin has been actived!");
    }

    public void onDisable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Ultimate Command Pack Plugin has been disabled! This will give big problems to server.");
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {

        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Console will never need owner support.");
            return true;
        }

        Player player = (Player) sender;
        Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("contactowner")) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Owner: Herobrine112211. Live chat skype: gangsteris33.");
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("heal")) {
            if (args.length == 0) {
                player.setHealth(20f);
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your health is now full!");
                return true;
            }
            if (target == null) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be healed!");
                return true;
            }
            target.setHealth(20f);
            target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + player.getName() + " healed you!");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " is healed!");
        }

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("feed")) {
            if (args.length == 0) {
                player.setFoodLevel(20);
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your hunger is now full!");
                return true;
            }
            if (target == null) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be feeded!");
                return true;
            }
            target.setFoodLevel(20);
            target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + player.getName() + " fed you!");
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " hunger is now full!");
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I get this stacktrace:

```
5:02:27 AM [ERROR] null
5:02:27 AM org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'heal' in plugin UltimateCommandPack v1.0.0
5:02:27 AM at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
5:02:27 AM at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:140) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
5:02:27 AM at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R2.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:625) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
5:02:27 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:1077) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
5:02:27 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:937) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
5:02:27 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.PacketPlayInChat.a(SourceFile:37) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
5:02:27 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.PacketPlayInChat.a(SourceFile:9) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
5:02:27 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
5:02:27 AM at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_75]
5:02:27 AM at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_75]
5:02:27 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:60) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
5:02:27 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:670) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
5:02:27 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.DedicatedServer.A(DedicatedServer.java:336) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
5:02:27 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.MinecraftServer.z(MinecraftServer.java:626) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
5:02:27 AM at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:534) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
5:02:27 AM at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_75]
5:02:27 AM Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
5:02:27 AM at me.herobrine112211.ulticmdpack.System.onCommand(System.java:29) ~[?:?]
5:02:27 AM at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-61ef214]
5:02:27 AM ... 15 more
```

Comment: Please consider adding the full error stack trace to your question.

Comment: getPlayer(args[0]); this piece say is deprecated. getPlayer is crossed(strikethrough)

Comment: The method getPlayer(String) from the type Server is deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error you get isn't related to that piece of code.

[`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

`args` may change depending on user input.
See [Check the arguments length](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial#Check_the_arguments_length) from the [official plugin tutorial](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial).

```
if (args.length == 0) {
    player.sendMessage("Please specify the target.");
    return true;
}
```

The deprecation message is not an error, it is a warning.
You can always ignore it, code will compile anyway.
You may want to hide it: hover the yellow-highlighted, crossed text and click *Add @SuppressWarnings 'deprecation'*.

From [Spigot Javadoc](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/), note that [`Server.getPlayer(String)`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Server.html#getPlayer(java.lang.String)) isn't marked as `@Deprecated`.
Maybe an IDE glitch? Try `File >> Save All`.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue from the stacktrace could be this line:

`Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);`

You need to check if args.length > 0 before you do this, the args array could be empty and you're trying to access elements in it.

Answer (score 1):

`Bukkit.getPlayer(String)` is [not deprecated in new `Spigot`](http://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Server.html#getPlayer(java.lang.String)) versions, but, it is [deprecated in older `Bukkit` versions](https://bukkit.org/threads/deprecated-getplayer-string-name.250555/), due to the switch from usernames to `UUIDs` in **1.8**.

In Bukkit, deprecated methods almost never get removed. They are only there to notify you of changes in new Minecraft versions. So, it would be safe to just ignore the warnings, as `Bukkit.getPlayer(String)` will keep working.

---

If you want to hide of the warning, you could use:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
```

Above your code that gets the player:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
```

You get an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Which are thrown to:

> Indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.
>
> <sup>(from the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html))</sup>

Whenever the player that runs the command does not have any arguments (for example, if they run `/heal` instead of `/heal Notch`)

To fix this, you should send the player an error message if they don't enter any arguments:

```
if(args.length == 0){
    //send the sender an error message, and return true

    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Correct usage: /" + commandLabel + " <player>"
    return true;
}
```

So, here's what your code could look like:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {

    if(!(sender instanceof Player)) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Console will never need owner support.");
        return true;
    }

    Player player = (Player) sender;
    
    if(args.length == 0){
        //send the sender an error message, and return true

        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Correct usage: /" + commandLabel + " <player>"
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

    //the rest of your code
}
```